# Как загрузить запись из базы данных?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

У меня в базе данных есть таблица "Школы". Загружаю ее в DataGridView так:

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Школы";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
conn.Open();
da.Fill(ds, "Школы");
conn.Close();
dataGridView2.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView2.DataMember = "Школы";
```

Названия школ, хранящихся в столбце "Название", я загрузил в comboBox.

Как мне теперь при выборе названия школы из comboBox загрузить отдельно запись этой школы в dataGridView2.

1. Это должно происходить как я понял в функции

   ```
   private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   ```
2. SQL-запрос наверное будет выглядить примерно так:

   ```
   string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Школы WHERE Название=" + comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
   ```

Помогите составить полный код функции `comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged()`.

Comment: Не пишите php. Используйте сохраненные процедуры.

Comment: Что-то я не понял. Где тут PHP?

Comment: PHP-style.